# Cannot reach AWS Fargate task through ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, amazon-alb

I've got a web application running as an AWS ECS Fargate task.  The task consists of 2 Docker containers - nginx exposing port 80, running as reverse proxy, forwarding queries to an asp.net core web application exposing port 5000.  The url configured in nginx.conf for upstream server is 127.0.0.1:5000, and the task is setup with container networking (awsvpc).

The ECS Service is defined as an autoscaling group of 1 task.  When I run the service, AWS sets up an elastic ENI with a public and private ip.  I can hit that public ip in a browser and get back a response from my web app, so it seems the ECS part is setup properly.

Next - I've defined an ALB with an http port 80 listener forwarding to a target group for the ECS Service.  The target group shows the private ip for the task ENI, so it appears to be setup correctly.  Health checks are configured as simple "/", and the task as well as ALB target group report them to be healthy.

However - when I navigate to the DNS name for the LB, I'm unable to get a response.

Additionally - this is running in a non-default VPC.  Route table includes an IGW.

Not sure what else I should be checking, so would appreciate some help in troubleshooting further.

Comment: ALB with Internet facing?

Comment: Internet facing, yes.  I think I figured it out  The VPC security group was configured incorrectly, it was not allowing communication with the ECS security group.  Once I opened them up, it started working.